# How add column with time difference in Sqlite (python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to update a table (sqlite database) adding column with constant value. However I am having some issues. I create table with

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE users(col1 text, col2 text, 
                dateCol datetime default current_timestamp,
                diff float)''')
```

Then I insert values into the table using

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, dateCol) 
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (n1_, n2_, n3_))
```

When I add constant values using following it works.

```
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE users SET 'diff' = 0.11 ''')
```

However, I want to insert time difference between dateCol with the newest record. How can I update my table adding difference in time (in seconds) with most recent (newest) record and all other records?

Comment: Do you know how to get the time of the newest record? How to compute the difference between timestamps? How to use subqueries?

Comment: Yes. I am reading it from a file and inserting into the table. I read a file (parse lines to get timestamps) and has **n3_** has a new timestamp which I pass to the SQL command.                    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, dateCol) 
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (n1_,  n2_ , **n3_**))

Comment: Which of my three questions did you answer with "yes"? If all three, you wouldn't need to ask your question …

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. Yes, was for your first answer. I know the time of the newest record n3_ which I am reading from a file. Now I wanted to do something like cursor.execute('''SELECT dateCol, timediff(date,?) as 'diff' FROM table''') as in MySQL, but seems like sqlite doesn't have timediff function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no [date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to compute differences, but this is possible by using a numeric [date format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime):

```sql
UPDATE users
SET diff =   julianday((SELECT MAX(dateCol) FROM users))
           - julianday(dateCol);
```